# Is there any way to send the event between the service and component in angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-modal

I am using angular2-modal for the modal alert. I just want to get the confirm event from the modal. How can I get that?

Comment: There are plenty of ways to do it. Did you try to search it? Would be also great if you provide more context about your problem

Comment: I am using shlomiassaf/angular2-modal. Here is the link You can check this plnkr. In the plukr, you can see custom-modal-sample.ts file. Please look at this function, onKeyUp(value). In this function, if the user enter 5, then the modal will be closed. I want to get the event in the app.component.ts. Is it helpful to clear?

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/U038cM?p=preview

Comment: That is very helpful. Can you add the close button to the custom-modal-sample.ts and get the event by clicking the button in the app.component.ts?

Comment: @yurzui, I just want to know which button is clicked in the app.component,ts. Is there any way for this?

Answer (score 0):

I can implemented this based on @yurzui's answers.
When we close the modal, we use this function,

```html
this.dialog.close();
```

If we use the function with the parameter, then we can get the result which button is clicked.